# Swift: scrollview autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I need to display some information in a scrollview and it should look like this:

[image]

First view has defined height but second one has dynamic height. I know how to make it dynamic but I don't know how to make it in scroll view. It tried to do it but it doesn't work. Any idea how to make this scene in a scrollview ?

Without scrollview:

[image]

Inside. scrollview:

[image]

Comment: A good article about scrollview with dynamic constraints can be found [here](http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/setting-dynamic-constraints-on-scrollview-in-ios/)

Comment: You need to show something you have tried. No one will do your work here.

Comment: I made these views and embeded them in scrollview however it doesn't work

Comment: What about table view instead?

Comment: Is it good idea to use table view instead ?

Comment: You should use UITableview instead of UIScrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view is vertically scrolling only, you should use a `UITableView` rather than a `UIScollView`

Each of the distinct views in your table would be a `UITableViewCell`. For each cell set auto layout constraints for the contents, ensuring your constraints are attached to the top and bottom of the cell's content view. To make it even easier, consider using `UIStackView`s inside your cells.

Then in your table view controller…

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = <estimate of height>
```

… and your cells will resize themselves.

There are plenty of resources out there for autosizing table view cells…

- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells
- http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: I think for this a tableview is an overkill because you are dealing with a finite number of views (only 3). You can still achieve what you want by embedding your 2 views and UILabel correctly inside UIScrollView. See my suggestion below and that made by thewarri09.

Comment: If it's a fixed number of views, it's a prime candidate for static cells - an even better case for a tableview!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a definitive answer without more details... Based on info you gave I'd give the following generic solution:

Assuming you are using StroyBoard / Xib to design your view - Then you could setup your view as below:

```
-View (root view)

   -ScrollView

      -UIStackView (vertical stackview)

         -UIView (set static height and add all other components)

         -UILabel (dynamic label ie with No. of lines set to 0)

         -UIView (another view with static height set)
```

After...
 - using autlayout set the top, leading, trailing, bottom constraints for UIScrollView to the root view... 
 - using autolayout set the top, leading, trailing, bottom constraints for your UIStackView to those of the scrollview... 
 - using autolayout set the width of your UIStackView - you can make it to be equal to that of the root view but also you could give it any width you desire
 - using autolayout EITHER center your UIStackView on the Y axis (vertically) or set its top constraint to that of the root UIView as it needs to know its Y position...

With this, you should have your scrollview kicking in when the size of your content becomes larger than the screensize

If this is not what you are looking for then you'll have to provide more info or give clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your second view or label inside that view should not have a Height constraint.

For that Label, `set number of lines to '0'` and don't give it a height. But if it gives warning that second view requires Height constraint then give it a Height constraint with Low priority.